# How do I initialize a single character variable to a decimal number (with an initializer)

Tags: c, syntax

This is a question about C syntax.

I have this one-byte long character variable that I initialize thusly:

```
const char timeband = "\xe";
```

This initializes it to decimal value 14.  I'm using hex because I don't know how to specify decimal in the initializer.  How would I do that?

Setting the value with an assignment statement or using octal is not an option.

EDIT: I should have said

```
const char timeband[1] = "\xe";
```

And I still want to get away from hex.  Using '\xe' doesn't answer the question.

Comment: You are trying to assign a *string* to a `char` here.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are looking for `const char timeband[1] = { 14 };` There is no need to go fancy with the hexadecimal notation.

Comment: You should have tried compiling that before posting it. You can't initialize an array with an integer constant. (This comment refers to the original version of the question, which has since been edited.)

Comment: @KeithThompson The original question was about a scalar, not an array. The OP changed the question, and I did not update the answer correctly.

Comment: Not the correct answer. The author is asking to set a scalar not an array. Please edit

EDIT: I realized that the OP changed his question. Ignore my downvote, SO does not allow me to cancel it.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to specify decimal character values within a string literal.

You can do this

```
const char timeband[1] = { 14 };
```

For long strings, this kind of initialisation can get real tedious real quick:

```
const char foo[] = { '1', '2', '3', 14 };
```

but that's what you've got if you want decimal.

Comment: Not the correct answer. The author is asking to set a scalar not an array. Please edit

EDIT: I realized that the OP changed his question. Ignore my downvote, SO does not allow me to cancel it.

Answer (score 1):

For single characters, you need to use single quotes:

```
const char timeband = '\xe';
```

Comment: The OP does not want a single character.

Answer (score -2):

I'm going to answer my own question:

**You can't do it.**